# PHP - Find certain strings in a variable

Tags: php, string, variables

My latest issue involves trying to find "http://" in a variable.  This variable contains the contents of a comments section on a clients website.  I have seen all kinds of answers but none of them seem to work.  I looked at a few other posts on here and I have yet to get the best answer.  Here is what I have so far:

```
if(strpos($comments, 'http://') == true) {
  // Does stuff here
}
```

I noticed other people use preg_match and some said to do it in an array.  I am getting confused, too many options.  Just kidding.  I would like some clarification though and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In that post they did === instead of ==, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to say:

```
if(strpos($comments, 'http://') !== false) {
```

...since it can return 0 (which is falsey) if `http://` is at the beginning of the string.

NOTE: This will only find the first occurrence of `http://` in the string.

Take a close look at the reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: So >= will search the whole string?

Comment: `strpos()` will search the whole string until the first occurrence of the needle is found or until end-of-string is reached.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give this a try and see how it turns out.  The main thing I am trying to do is block links in the comments.

Comment: Actually, `str_ireplace()` may be more what you want, then. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

Comment: Would this work even if I don't want to replace the http://?  In most cases I get spam comments like "byfrgpvsipvtfok, habyqiupyh , [url=http://www.---------------.com]ceasdfasdfasdfg[/url], http://www.--------------.com habyqiupyh", I want to keep the form from submitting when it comes across the http://.

Comment: If you want to block the comment altogether, then just check it with `stripos()`. If you want to strip URLs, then use `str_ireplace()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, at least judging from the example in the question asked. This if will evaluate to `true` if and only if there is an `http://` somewhere in the string. Perhaps you wanted the opposite? If so, this isn't obvious from your question.

Comment: My mistake.  I have the test page loaded in a test directory and I kept submitting the form on the live page.  I just realized because I got a call from my client wondering what all the new entries were from my ip.  Your answer did work and I gave the check.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change code like that:

```
if(strpos($comments, 'http://') === false) {
```

//no link
}

because strpos return integer which is position your string.

Example:
full string: "http://stackoverflow.com hello"
you finding: "http"

Naturally it return 0.

But 
full string: "ahttp://stackoverflow.com"
you finding: "http"

it return 1.

So you must use === operator to check is really 'boolean false'.

If you try to check with == operator, you maybe get fail because it get 0 as false.

more detail: http://php.net/strpos

Answer (score 0):

I found this was a better match: (recommended by phpstorm ide)

```
if(str_contains($e, '1062 Duplicate entry')) {
            
}
```